# Dual-booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu, have boot error 0xC0000098

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot

I had Windows 8 pre-installed on my Asus laptop, and then I installed Ubuntu. I couldn't boot Windows 8 from Grub, but I could enter the bios and set Windows as the first boot device and Windows 8 would boot just fine. I just wanted to have it like [this](http://www.globalnerdy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/windows-8-multiboot-screen.jpg).

I installed EasyBCD nero tool and made a mess. After rebooting with Windows 8 as the first boot device, I got the following screen:

[image: Boot Error 0xC0000098]

I can boot to Ubuntu but I cant boot Windows 8. I tried automatic repair and `fixmbr` commands on the command prompt but nothing worked...

Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried booting to the recovery partition on your computer? There may be ways to rebuild the BCD there. Also, I seem to remember some ASUS computers come with the original Windows disc. If yours does, maybe have a look at [this](http://www.tweakhound.com/2012/11/13/how-to-fix-the-windows-bootloader/).

Comment: EasyBCD and Nero have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [bootrec](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392) tool for rebuild bcd.
At the prompt command, type the `bootrec` command as shown below and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Comment: It still causes problems could you check this? http://paste.ubuntu.com/5890749/ I used boot repair